# What is the name of the animal that follows its master, and is also a figment of the master's imagination?

Tags: dnd-5e, summoning, content-identification

The animal follows its master, and is also a figment of the master's imagination. It can be re-summoned. I think you can see through its eyes.

- What is its name?
- And what animals can it be?
- Also, what class do you have to be in order to get it?

I think I might want one.

Comment: If you are asking about a pooka, as shown in the play "Harvey" and movie "Harvey" with James Stewart ... then there's your answer. Are you asking only about an in game creature?  Have you got a copy of the Players Handbook?  Do you have access to the Monster Manual?

Comment: This question may need to be closed/locked as a ["read the book to me"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5270/22566) kind of question.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Nah, it’s not a good question, but it is a what is this question? With their comment below about eidolons, I do think verifying edition may be a good idea.

Comment: @NotArch I am not so sure. Previous input from this contributor shows a lack of the basics, such as doing research before asking a question.  Seems that a failure to accept the welcome, take the [tour], check out [help] and review the [ask] and [answer] is how this querent repays the offer of the time, effort, and expertise of contributors to this Stack. Apparently, has not considered it worth the effort.  I'll stick by "this is a read me the book" question.  Not sure if others see the same thing I do.

Comment: OP has confirmed that this question stemmed from a podcast they were listening to and were interested in this mechanic. However, the podcast is Sword Art Online:AOD, which is a pathfinder podcast, not dnd-5e.

Answer (score 10):

#### I think you’re looking for the *find familiar* spell.

[*Find familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) states:

> You gain the service of a familiar, a spirit that **takes an animal form you choose: bat, cat, crab, frog (toad), hawk, lizard, octopus, owl, poisonous snake, fish (quipper), rat, raven, sea horse, spider, or weasel.** Appearing in an unoccupied space within range, the familiar has the statistics of the chosen form, though it is a celestial, fey, or fiend (your choice) instead of a beast.
>
> Your familiar acts independently of you, but it always obeys your commands. In combat, it rolls its own initiative and acts on its own turn. A familiar can't attack, but it can take other actions as normal.
>
> When the familiar drops to 0 hit points, it disappears, leaving behind no physical form. It reappears after you cast this spell again. As an action, you can temporarily dismiss the familiar to a pocket dimension. Alternatively, you can dismiss it forever. **As an action while it is temporarily dismissed, you can cause it to reappear in any unoccupied space within 30 feet of you.** Whenever the familiar drops to 0 hit points or disappears into the pocket dimension, it leaves behind in its space anything it was wearing or carrying.
>
> While your familiar is within 100 feet of you, you can communicate with it telepathically. **Additionally, as an action, you can see through your familiar's eyes and hear what it hears** until the start of your next turn, gaining the benefits of any special senses that the familiar has. During this time, you are deaf and blind with regard to your own senses.
>
> You can't have more than one familiar at a time. If you cast this spell while you already have a familiar, you instead cause it to adopt a new form. Choose one of the forms from the above list. Your familiar transforms into the chosen creature.
>
> Finally, when you cast a spell with a range of touch, your familiar can deliver the spell as if it had cast the spell. Your familiar must be within 100 feet of you, and it must use its reaction to deliver the spell when you cast it. If the spell requires an attack roll, you use your attack modifier for the roll.

This spell appears on the Wizard spell list, so you can get it by being a wizard. You can also get it as a warlock by choosing the Pact of the Chain pact boon, or as a bard with the Magical Secrets feature. You can also learn it as part of the Magic Initiate feat.

Notably, the familiar is *not* a figment of the caster’s imagination, but is actually an incarnation of a fey, fiend, or celestial spirit.

Comment: what level do i have to be? and do i have to be a specific race? is that all the forms it can take or can I have a wolf/dog?

Comment: @Drakethedragon Wizards can use it at 1st level, Warlocks must be 3rd level, College of Lore bards can get it at 6th, and all other bards can get it at 10th. The forms it takes are only the ones listed.

Comment: @Drakethedragon As for your previous questions, I _strongly_ recommended to read the PHB...

Comment: @Drakethedragon I second Eddymage’s recommendation. [The basic rules are available for free](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules).

Comment: what is the hp of the familiar

Comment: @Drakethedragon The hp of the familiar is the hp of whatever creature it took the form of. Familiars are *extremely* fragile. Most forms only have 1 hitpoint, the sturdiest is an Octopus with 3. The exception being a Warlock that chooses the 3rd level Pact of the Chain feature, and can summon an Imp, Pseudodragon, Quasit, or Sprite. The sturdiest of these is the Imp with 10hp.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin It was a pretty straightforward content identification problem. “What feature of this game has these characteristics?” is not that unusual of a question type here, so I’m not sure what your comment about closure is implying.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin The close/clarify/reopen process isn't a contortion - it's literally how we work to best answer someone's question. If something isn't clear, we don't get guess and hope we got it right, we ask for clarification so that everyone can answer appropriately for the issue at hand.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov What I mean is that the question very prominently asks about such a creature that is a figment of the imagination. But it also (including from previous questions) is clear the OP does not have a firm grasp of the rules at all. I did refrain from answering as I was concerned about getting reprimanded for not clarifying first -- you could have asked them if they are sure it is a figment, where they have this info from etc. pp., and close for clarification. You chose not to, when it is not needed by expert judgment, and that is what I refer to.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin Ah, thanks for clarifying. In the future, I’d prefer you didn’t use “+1” comments to subtly air your negative opinions about how I use the site. [There is a place](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/) for discussing general best practices for content curation.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov In this case, this was not intended to air a negative opinion on you, but a positive one, I'm sorry it came across this way. In any case, I think this also is a correct and well designed answer, earning a +1 even outside such considerations.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I agree with Nobody, their comment is a positive one, not a negative one. They're saying "thank you for not making this complicated"

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin I was just wondering what is was because the podcast I am listing to said it was from the user inanimation and was called an idilon

Comment: @Drakethedragon podcasts and live play series often bend the rules for fun, and are set in their own worlds where some things work differently. I wouldn't base an expectation of real rules from any of these shows. They can be fun, but if you actually want to play DND properly you need to read the rules and understand them. I admire your enthusiasm from watching a podcast but real games tend to be pretty different

Comment: @Drakethedragon They're most likely calling it an "eidolon," an ancient Greek term. As SeriousBri said, it's probably just a different name they're using for flavor. In any case, you should probably mark this answer as Accepted.

Comment: @Drakethedragon There is actually a monster called Idolon in D&D 5e, but it has little other similarity with what you describe

Comment: @Drakethedragon it's also possible the podcast included someone using a homebrewed class--or you weren't listening to a D&D podcast. There's a *Pathfinder* (1 and 2E) class called a "Summoner" whose main ability/playstyle is to conjure up a creature to fight on its behalf, and this creature is called an Eidolon. So it's possible you were listening to a Pathfinder podcast, or that someone had homebrewed in their own version of the same class into D&D.

Comment: @guildsbounty does the spell to re-summon it take longer based on the Eidolons level

Comment: @Drakethedragon Not in Pathfinder. But again, people make stuff up and add it to TTRPGs all the time. So again...if you really want to understand how D&D works before people start modding it, you need to read the rules. D&D, and TTRPGs as a whole, are a lot like Skyrim...they are so easily, frequently, and often heavily modded that figuring out what the base game is like can be hard if all you do is watch Let's Plays

Comment: @Drakethedragon a good question might be "how much of podcast X is based on the rules and how much is made up". If we have other viewers then you might find out a lot more.

Comment: @SeriousBri “What homebrew rules does X use” might be a more objective way to phrase that.

Comment: @Drakethedragon can you link us to the podcast so we can confirm edition?

Comment: Spotify sword art online: AOD

Comment: @Drakethedragon It looks like that isn’t 5e, but pathfinder.